# !Dimension too large when knitting file to PDF using rmarkdown in RStudio

Tags: pdf, compiler-errors, r-markdown

I receiving the following error when I try to knit into a pdf:

```
! Dimension too large.
\fb@put@frame ...p \ifdim \dimen@ >\ht \@tempboxa 
                                                  \fb@putboxa #1\fb@afterfra...
```

It's an extremely long line of code that I need to knit into a pdf (about 5000 lines). A lot of preprocessing data. The output itself is quite small maybe a line or more. Has anyone had this issue with huge blocks of code? If so, could you tell me how you solved it? I'm up for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a LaTeX `framed` package error.  RMarkdown tries to put all of that code into a single environment (I believe it's a `snugshade` environment, but I might be wrong), and that environment isn't ready for something that's going to stretch over many pages.  The most I managed to get was about 1300 lines which were broken up into 48 pages of code.

The simplest solution would be to break that up into 4 or 5 pieces, but that might not be easy for you to do.

Next simplest might be not to show it as code at all:  use `echo = FALSE` in the code chunk that runs it, and include it some other way (e.g. in a verbatim environment, or using the `listings` package).  With that much code, showing it as a couple of hundred pages of text doesn't really make much sense anyway.

Comment: So, like into 3 or 4 chunks of 1.3K lines of code, right?

Comment: If that's feasible, I'd give it a try.  The 1300 lines that worked for me were very short (just the numbers 1:1300); it might be that realistic line lengths have a different limit.